# I want to calculate values based on the same Dateframe.. the new values have to be appended to the Dateframe . How to do that?

Tags: pandas, append, concatenation, calculated-columns

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Neuer Ordner\Strompreis.csv',
             sep=';',
            encoding = 'unicode_escape',
            index_col=0,
            parse_dates=True
            )
dd = list()
for i in range (0,5):

        x = df.values[len(df)-5]
        y = df.values[len(df)-3]
        z = 0.5*x + 0.7*y
        dd.append(z)
        dx = pd.DataFrame(dd)
        df = pd.concat([df, dx])
```

This is the head of the input dataframe

```
                     Strompreis
Daten   
2019-11-25 22:45:00     34.97
2019-11-25 23:00:00     48.61
2019-11-25 23:15:00     36.66
2019-11-25 23:30:00     36.74
2019-11-25 23:45:00     33.83
```

The expected Outputs must include the new values of z, like

```
Strompreis
Daten   
2019-11-25 22:45:00     34.97
2019-11-25 23:00:00     48.61
2019-11-25 23:15:00     36.66
2019-11-25 23:30:00     36.74
2019-11-25 23:45:00     33.83
2019-11-25 00:00:00     41.5
2020-01-01 00:15:00     36.9
2020-01-01 00:30:00     45.9
...
```

the value of z2 must be calculated based on the new dataframe (including z1)

Comment: Please show a hard coded example of an input dataframe and what your expected outputs from this dataframe should look like.

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks for replying.  the input and the expected dataframe can be found below

Comment: it is better if you edited your question and added the input and expected output dataframes the question.

Comment: On line 6 of your expected outputs, where did the value of the index come from and how did you calculate 41.5?

Comment: t = pd.date_range(start=(df.index[len(df)-1]) , periods=n, freq='15min')
new_df = pd.DataFrame([[x, y] for x,y in zip(t, z)], columns=["Daten", "Strompreis"])
df = pd.concat([df,new_df])
#41.5 is the value of z for (i=1)